# Conditional Expected Value

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to figure out the following case; suppose that I have a supermarket where I give points to my customers for they to redeem (1 point for 1 dollar).
   Once in a while I send offers to my customers so that they have 2 points for each dollar, for a limited time. But they have to accept this offer (i.e. they have to subscribe to it).
   I'd like to forecast at the beginning of the year how much extra those who accept will spend during the offer time. Let's say that I have historic data on offer acceptance, as well as how much extra they spent during the offer time.

I'm having a hard time trying to put together a prediction model for this. I guess I need first a binary model to predict out of all my customers those who will accept, and then a second regression model with the input of the previous model, to predict the extra $ and then calculate the expected extra revenue?

Appreciate any help on this!
Thank you!

Comment: You've outlined on possible way to approach this problem. Can you clarify what your question is? There is no sentence ending in $?$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use different methods. One is the one suggested in your question and another one is the use of regime-switching regression where you assume there is an ongoing regime in your time-series that is time dependent and not observable. In this case there would be two regimes to your time-series which is having/not having the promotional offer.

Another thing to consider is adding features to the model to better explain the space of your outcomes.For example: Sexuality, Income,...